# How to read Telugu table items from pdf in python 3

Tags: python, tabula

I am using this following source code for fetching English table data from pdf. But I am unable to fetch other languages. Could anyone help me to how to pass the language parameter and fetch any type of language

```
from tabula import read_pdf

url = "/Users/administrator/Desktop/Telugu_land_document1.pdf"

try:
    df = read_pdf(url, pages='all')
    print(df)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the coordinate information so that it has nothing to do with the language.

```
df = tabula.read_pdf_with_template("/path/xxx.pdf", "path/temp.json")
```

`# cat path/temp.json`

```
[
  {
    "page":1,
    "extraction_method":"a",
    "x1":157.18,
    "x2":1111.41,
    "y1":270.97,
    "y2":283,
    "width":954.23,
    "height":11.189
  },
  {
    "page":1,
    "extraction_method":"a",
    "x1":157.18,
    "x2":1111.41,
    "y1":270.97,
    "y2":283,
    "width":954.23,
    "height":11.189
  }
  ...
]
```